# Finding a tuple with two keys

Tags: list, erlang, key, tuples

For Example:

```
Db = [{pid1, {key1, {apple}}}, {pid1, {key2, {banana}}}, {pid1, {key3, {watermelon}}}, {pid2, {key1, {cucumber}}}, {pid2, {key2, {carrot}}}].
```

Being able to return the tuple where Pid = pid1, and Key = key1, which would be {pid1, {key1, {apple}}}. How would I go about doing this? Something similar to the BIF lists:keyfind/3.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to break early when you find the value, you can implement it yourself using pattern matching:

```
pidkeyfind(_Pid, _Key, []) -> false;
pidkeyfind(Pid, Key, [Head = {Pid, {Key, _}} | _Tail]) -> Head;
pidkeyfind(Pid, Key, [_|Tail]) -> pidkeyfind(Pid, Key, Tail).
```

Comment: this works and is more didactic, but it supposes that there is at most 1 record that matches the request, if it is the case, it should be faster in average.

Comment: Pascal, indeed. I chose this interpretation (single hit) because that's how lists:keyfind/3 works.

Answer (score 1):

with lists:filter/2 it should work, here is an example of how to use it.

```
1> Db = [{pid1, {key1, {apple}}}, {pid1, {key2, {banana}}}, {pid1, {key3, {watermelon}}}, {pid2, {key1, {cucumber}}}, {pid2, {key2, {carrot}}}].
[{pid1,{key1,{apple}}},
 {pid1,{key2,{banana}}},
 {pid1,{key3,{watermelon}}},
 {pid2,{key1,{cucumber}}},
 {pid2,{key2,{carrot}}}]
2> Find = fun (K1,K2,L) -> lists:filter( fun({X,{Y,_}}) -> X =:= K1 andalso Y =:= K2 end,L) end.
#Fun<erl_eval.18.82930912>
3> Find(pid1,key1,Db).
[{pid1,{key1,{apple}}}]
```

Answer (score 1):

There are several ways to perform such lookups, and no best method. It is mostly **a matter of style**.

- You can write a **recursive function** that will return as soon as the result is matched, as [suggested](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19398877/2617867) by [@Emil Vikström](https://stackoverflow.com/users/238978/emil-vikstrom). The advantage is that you do not go through all the elements but the lookup will return as soon as a result is found, similar to what [`lists:keyfind/3`](http://erlang.org/doc/man/lists.html#keyfind-3) does. However, one could argue that if the list is long enough to justify such an optimization, another data structure could be more appropriate (like a sorted list or a tree).
- You can use [**`lists:filter/2`**](http://erlang.org/doc/man/lists.html#filter-2) as [suggested by @Pascal](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19398826/2617867). This has the advantage over a recursive function to be based on a library function, which is always good for code maintenance.
- You can use a filter within a **list comprehension**. This is similar than the `lists:filter/2` approach, but a little shorter. Many see lists comprehension as more Erlang-like than using `lists:map/2` and `lists:filter/2`, especially when the test is so short.

  `[T || {Pid, {Key, _Value}} = T <- Db, Pid =:= MyPid, Key =:= MyKey].`

  If key1 and pid1 are constants, you can even write:

  `[T || {pid1, {key1, _Value}} = T <- Db].`